# How to change an HTML element that uses CSS by using jQuery and XML data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I have a site that shows system status that has a colored bar behind it depending on the health of the system it displays.  My HTML that uses the jQuery is:

```
<script> 
  function myExampleSite() 
  {
    var myURL = window.location.href;
    var dashIndex = myURL.lastIndexOf("-");
    var dotIndex = myURL.lastIndexOf(".");
    var result = myURL.substring(dashIndex + 1, dotIndex);
    return result;
  }

  var exampleSite = myExampleSite();
</script>

<script> 
var root = null;
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $.get("Status_Pages.xml",
    function (xml)
    {
        root = $(xml).find("site[name='" + exampleSite + "']");

        var status = $(root).find("systemStatus");
        var color = status.attr("color");
        $("#status").html(status.text());
        $("#status").attr("color", color);

        result = $(root).find("networkNotes");
        $("#networkNotes").html($(result).text());

        result = $(root).find("headerImage");
        $("td#headerImage").html($(result).text());

       ....etc etc
    });
});
</script>
```

My XML file looks like this.

```
<sites>
   <site name="Template"> 
       <headerImage>images/template-header.png</headerImage>
       <productVersion>[Version goes here]</productVersion>
       <systemStatus color="green">Normal</systemStatus>
       <networkNotes>System status is normal</networkNotes>
    </site>
</sites>
```

I have several `<site>`s that all have their own data that will populate different areas of individual sites.  I've ran into a snag though.

The way I am displaying my status currently looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="table_header">
        Current System Status
    </td>
</tr>
    <table><tr>

        <td id="status"></td>

    </tr></table>

    <tr>
        <td class="table_header">
        Network Notes
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Right now it's hard-coded to show the system status with either a red, green, or yellow bar behind the text to indicate the health of the system, but I need to make able to read the XML value for that site.

The tricky part is that I am also using data from a CSS for this particular portion of the site.  The CSS code relevant to this is (there is one for green, yellow, and red):

```
#status[color=green] {
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    background: url(images/greenbar.jpg) no-repeat;
}

#status[color=yellow] {
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    background: url(images/yellow.jpg) no-repeat;
}

#status[color=red]{
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    background: url(images/red.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

**How can I read in the system status string, along with the element's attribute of `color` to populate my HTML so that each site has a different image depending on what's in the XML? **

I have tried the above and it gives a color background to the text, not the image url background.

And it reads the correct status but the image never appears behind it.

Comment: `#normal_status` is an ID rather than a class, and as per HTML spec, no two elements should have the same ID.

Comment: Only 1 element has `#normal_status`.  I showed what was in the CSS as well as the HTML.  The only place it's used in the HTML is what I showed before the CSS code block.

Comment: You should try and lower the threshold of answering your question. It's kind of a big read for what appears to be a small problem. Try to construct a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/). The key to solving big problems is breaking them down to small ones. You might even end up finding your own solution. jsfiddle is a nice tool to help with the self contained bit.

Comment: I assume, a color represents a status? Example, `green==normal`, `red==down` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you have information in your XML that you want to show in your HTML. And depending on the status/content of your XML, you also want it to be shown/presented/styled differently using CSS.

With CSS, you can select things, using ID, class or in the case of `[color=green]`, attributes. But the code that you have supplied, you haven't attached the `color` attribute to your HTML. So to make this work, with the CSS that you have, you need to do something like

```
var status = $(root).find("systemStatus"); 
var color = status.attr("color"); //get the attribute value from the XML
$("#status").attr("color", color); //assign the attribute value to the HTML
$("#status").html(status.text());
result = $(root).find("networkNotes");
$("#networkNotes").html($(result).text());
```

[An example of this](http://jsfiddle.net/mfirdaus/yQJpL/)

But moving forward, semantically, I think you don't need to use `color="green"`. It actually not be the "correct" way (in terms of  content and presentation seperation). I would actually suggest using classes and assign them based on the actual "status". So example `normal`,`warning` and `danger`. Then you can simply have the color information (or "presentation" information) be in the CSS file.

So your XML for status will be something like

```
<systemStatus>Normal</systemStatus>
```

and the jQuery code would be something like

```
var status = $(root).find("systemStatus").text();
$("#status").html(status);
$("#status").attr("class", status.toLowerCase());
```

and your css will be something like

```
#status.normal {
    background:green
}
#status.congested {
    background:yellow;
    color:black
}

#status.down {
    background:red
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mfirdaus/Kc64p/)

Comment: This is **exactly** what I was looking for.  Thanks so much for your help!  I am assuming I can do this without buttons and just change it around a little so I'll give you the bounty and accepted answer.  Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah. The buttons are just to simulate a `$.get()`. And you're welcome. glad to be of help :)

Comment: I figured as much, and thanks again!  I have a similar question open regarding inserting IDs into image tags.  I don't have enough rep to bounty it anymore but if you've got time, I'd greatly appreciate it.  [The question is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688085/how-to-change-an-image-on-a-site-using-xml-data-jquery)

Comment: For some reason, it's not working with my image URL I am using for the background.  There are specific "bar" backgrounds that I am to use for this, and instead of using background: green; I am trying to use background: url(images/greenbar.jpg) and it's not working.  Any ideas? (It works when I hard-code it).

Comment: just wondering, have you tried it with single quotes? like background: url('images/greenbar.jpg');

Comment: I have.  I edited the question to show my current code and the current issue.  I keep getting black text with a red background instead of the red bar image.  I've tried with and without quotes and it doesn't seem to work.